# How does the Luck stat work in Golden Sun?

Tags: golden-sun

What exactly does the Luck stat do, and how should I manage it? E.g. should I boost one player's stat to boost pickups/drops, or boost all to increase critical hits/weapon unleashes?

(To specify, I'm not asking if I should do one or the other, I'm basing that comparison off the assumption that it might work similar to how it does in other games.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [Golden Sun wikia](https://goldensunwiki.net/wiki/Luck):

> Luck is the statistic that determines a character's **chance of being inflicted by a status inflicting problem attached to an ability** used against you, such as Sleep and Stun.

> It does not increase your own chance of inflicting said status effects onto opponents, contrary to common belief. Having a luck rating of 40 or higher provides immunity to Poison, Venom, Haunt, Death Curse, the target's HP being instantly reduced to 1, and being forced out of battle.

So it does not have any effect on pickup, drops or critical hits, apparently.