# Does "Mortal Danger" work on Deadbeard?

Tags: golden-sun

Been replaying Golden Sun, and I've currently got the Assassin's Blade equipped. This weapon has a chance to unleash its special effect "Mortal Danger", which either deals extra damage (I believe it's just a critical hit) or a small chance of killing the opponent in one hit.

Does this work on bosses, specifically Deadbeard? Since he's one of the hardest bosses in the game.

Comment: It is more than 10 years ago since I played Golden Sun, but I remember specifically trying this on bosses, but I had no luck. However, just my little experiment (admittedly, without much patience) isn't enough to post as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

**Yes, it works on bosses**, but **No, it does not work on Deadbeard.**

The "Luck" stat acts as Status resistance. Having more of it makes you less susceptible to being affected by them. (You may be interested in revisiting this answer: [How does the Luck stat work in Golden Sun?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/390147/how-does-the-luck-stat-work-in-golden-sun))

Some bosses, including Deadbeard, have a Luck stat that gives complete immunity to status effects, which includes the Death effect from the Assassin's Blade Unleash ability.

You can find the exact formula [here](https://goldensunwiki.net/wiki/Luck) but a nice summary is:

> for every 2 Luck you have, all base effect chances against you have a subtractive 3% taken away

and [Deadbeard](https://goldensunwiki.net/wiki/Deadbeard) has 60 Luck.